# Changing variables with LV model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

reading analysis of Lotka-Volter model, I found folowing variable change to make it dependable only of one parameter.
Original equatations:
$$\frac{dN}{dt}=N(a-b\cdot P)$$
$$\frac{dP}{dt}=P(c\cdot N-d)$$
And we use following substitution:
$u(\tau)=\frac{c\cdot N(t)}{d};v(\tau)=\frac{b\cdot P(t)}{a};\tau=a\cdot t;\alpha=\frac{d}{a}$
and we get:
$$\frac{du}{d\tau}=u(1-v)$$
$$\frac{dv}{d\tau}=\alpha\cdot v(u-1)$$
To see it better I wanted to get from our new equatations original one, take first.
$$\frac{d}{d\tau}(\frac{c\cdot N(\frac{\tau}{a})}{d})=\frac{c\cdot N(t)}{d}(1-\frac{b\cdot P(t)}{a})$$
$$\frac{d N(\frac{\tau}{a})}{d\tau}\cdot \frac{1}{a}=N(t)(1-\frac{b\cdot P(t)}{a})$$
Now we multiply by $a$ and substitute $\tau=a\cdot t$
$$\frac{d N(t)}{d(ta)}=N(t)(a-b\cdot P(t))$$
So we get almost $1$ equatation. It seems that :$\frac{d N(t)}{d(ta)}=\frac{d N(t)}{d(t)}$ but I don't see it. I will be glad for simple explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per chain rule,
$$
\frac{d}{dτ}N(\frac τa)=N'(\frac τa)·\frac1a
$$
where the $N'$ in the outer derivative is the "simple, usual" derivative, $N'(t)=\frac{d}{dt}N(t)$. If you extract the inner derivative $\frac1a$, then you already have fully applied the chain rule.